# Need to Display Data From SQL in a Multiline TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

In process to integrate my Console based application to Web based application, I came across the following problem:

I need to **display data in a Multiline Text Box** (as per requirement) such that each record is displayed in the text box without overwriting the previous(it should be in the next line).

For Windows Forms I was using the following code:

```
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                predicted_grade = reader["Domain"].ToString();
                priority = "Priority: " + i;
                predicted_grade = priority +" --- "+predicted_grade + "\r\n";
                textBox2.AppendText(predicted_grade);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

But since AppendText property does not run in ASP.net Website, I don't Know how to do it. 
Please guide me, that how I should make the data appear as:

```
Code | Course Name | Predicted_Grade
1    |   Science   |  A+
2    |   Maths     |  B
3    |   History   |  C
```

using Multi line text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the AppendText functionality in ASP.NET pages by modifying your

```
predicted_grade = priority +" --- "+predicted_grade + "\r\n";
textBox2.AppendText(predicted_grade);
```

to

```
predicted_grade = priority +" --- "+predicted_grade + Environment.NewLine;
textBox2.Text += predicted_grade;
```

Or if you use `AppendText()` in many pages in your project, you can create an extension method `AppendText` to TextBox control:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this TextBox textBox, String text)
    {
        textBox.Text += text;
    }
}
```

To use it, just call:

```
predicted_grade = priority +" --- "+predicted_grade + Environment.NewLine;
textBox2.AppendText(predicted_grade);
```

You can also use the extension method to take care of the `\r\n` for you:

```
    public static void AppendLine(this TextBox textBox, String text)
    {
        textBox.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

To use it, just call:

```
predicted_grade = priority +" --- "+predicted_grade;
textBox2.AppendLine(predicted_grade);
```

P/S: `\r\n` won't work in ASP.Net TextBox, so you need to use NewLine as mentioned by Darren

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Environment.NewLine`:

```
textBox2.Text = predicted_grade + Environment.NewLine;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.environment.newline.aspx